# Connect to two different databases in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am thinking to connect to 2 database in my project in php.

one is an existing database from our ticketing system that uses MS ACESS and the other one is the one im using now its MYSQL.

The use of the MS access is just to retrieve data from it and the MYSQL will be used to both retrieve and store data.

Is it possible to connect to both database at the same time??

Comment: Why not? You can connect to as many databases you need.

Comment: so there will be no issue even on host and server to be used??

Comment: @Bert: It's perfectly technically possible (PHP has no limit build in for the number of database connections on such a low level), and PDO helps you to do this easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

Long answer: 
You should ensure that your code always uses connection identifiers to avoid confusion and have clean, readable code. (Especially when you connect to both databases using an abstraction layer like ODBC or PDO)

Please look into the [PHP Manual on PDO and connection management](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Example:

```
$link_mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$link_msaccess = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\\test.mdb");

// query MySQL DB
foreach($link_mysql->query('SELECT * FROM test') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}

// query MS Access DB
foreach($link_msaccess->query('SELECT * FROM omg_its_access') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Example without PDO:

```
$link_mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db("test", $link_mysql);

$link_msaccess = odbc_connect("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\\test.mdb");

// you may omit the link identifier for MySQL, but i suggest to use it explicitly 
$res1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test', $link_mysql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res1)) {
    print_r($row);
}
// for ODBC the link identifier is mandatory
$res2 = odbc_exec($link_msaccess, 'SELECT * FROM omg_its_access');
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($res2)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

**As you see above, the code for the two database drivers differs in its syntax - that is why i suggest to use PDO.**

PDO will avoid a lot of hassle and will make switching to another database driver much easier if you decide to do so later. It abstracts all database drivers and gives you a simple interface to handle them all with the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), for example, thats possible. just create one pdo-object for each connection - just use the [mysql-driver for mysql](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.3) and an [odbc-connection for access](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.7).

Comment: im not using PDO but i'll give it a shot.