# PHP: creating 2 PDOs for 2 different DBs, one blocks the second one

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqlite

I have 2 DBs: 1 in MySQL and the other one on SQLite3.

I need to insert the same data into both. To achieve this by a Form, I'm making a PHP script, that has some issue.
Here below the code then the explanation on what's going on:

```
// MySQL
try {
    $sql = new PDO($pdo_servername, $username, $password, $pdo_options);
    $sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $ret = $sql->exec($query);
    if(!$ret){
          echo $sql->lastErrorMsg();
          } else {
          echo "New record created successfully on MySQL DB";   
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
    $sql->close();



// SQLite
try {
    $sqlite = new PDO($pdo_servername_sqlite3);
    $sqlite->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $retlite = $sqlite->exec($query);
    if(!$retlite){
          echo $sqlite->lastErrorMsg();
          } else {
          echo "New record created successfully on SQLite3 DB"; 
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sqlite . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
    $sqlite->close();
```

The MySQL works fine, while the SQLite3 doesn't even start.
Inverting the blocks, thus first SQLite3 then MySQL, the issue is inverted: the SQLite3 works fine and MySQL doesn't start.
I have not any error returned

I tried also to avoid any try-catch-finally, and I just wrote the code as simple it is, and I got the same identical situation.
Is it forbidden to open 2 PDO connections, to 2 different DBs?
Where is my mistake please?

Comment: Interesting question, maybe this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30689/pdo-class-for-multiple-databases  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292789/connect-to-two-different-databases-in-php will be helpful.

Comment: In fact it's more the case of the second link. However on my case, it works always the very first database called. Never the second.
To be able to work with the second, I have to invert the order. Which I don't understand why

Comment: Can you try to set `$sql = NULL` and `$sqlite = NULL` after `->close()` ? Because the connection remains active for the lifetime of that `PDO` object. To close the connection, you need to *destroy* the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted - you do this by assigning `NULL` to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

Comment: Did it right now, following your suggestion. Nothing changes :-/

Comment: why do you `try...catch` ? you don't need it usually. that technique just hide some behavior from you.

Comment: OK,combine the 2 instances of the different connection into single `try-catch` block, one after another, then only execute the statements in another `try-catch` block

Comment: Could you show previous fragment where you initialize `$query` string?

Comment: @Alex - As I said into my post, also avoiding try - catch the result doesn't change. i still have this constant issue.

Comment: @bodi0 - I tired this solution already but it didn't work

Comment: Please @Alex , you find here the string:
    `$query = "INSERT INTO song (".$instert_into.") VALUES (".$values_to_be_in.")";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, that is the only breakpoint where you really need `try...catch`:

```
// MySQL
try {
    $sql = new PDO($pdo_servername, $username, $password, $pdo_options);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'MySQL connection failed: ' . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    $sql = false;
}

// SQLite
try {
    $sqlite = new PDO($pdo_servername_sqlite3);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'SQLite connection failed: '. "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    $sqlite = false;
}

if ($sql != false) {
  $ret = $sql->exec($query);
  if(!$ret){
      echo $sql->lastErrorMsg();
  } else {
      echo "New record created successfully on MySQL DB";   
  }
  $sql->close();
}

if ($sqlite != false) {
  $retlite = $sqlite->exec($query);
  if(!$retlite){
      echo $sqlite->lastErrorMsg();
  } else {
      echo "New record created successfully on SQLite3 DB"; 
  }
  $sqlite->close();
}
```

Comment: Copied, pasted and tried. I get the same issue, and I got some more detail:
With the list as you  posted: MySQL is working but not SQLite3.
if I flip the 2 "if" between eachother, making SQLite3 coming before MySQL, then SQLite3 is working and not MySQL.

Comment: Ok the issue is probably inside the "if"s. I tried now to avodi any "if" and to put jsut the 2 instrucitons  `$ret = $sql->exec($query);` `$retlite = $sqlite->exec($query);` and both DBs are updated.

Thus tehre shoudl be something wrong.
And I found that the instructions `$sql->close();` and `$sqlite->close();` should be put at the very end of the file. Then both DBs are updated. I find this very strange, because it's the very first action I did on my code. But probably the code itself was also causing the issue, while with your suggestion, and these small improvements, everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to thank everybody contributed here :)
I would like to post the definitive working code, because some line, should also be changed, respect the above code.
Indeed the PDO method `lastErrorMsg();` seems don't exist, and the same for the PDO  `method close();` It should be used `errorInfo()`in place of `lastErrorMsg();`and it's an array. While to close the DB connection: I read somewhere here on Stackoverflow that when the script execution ends, automatically PDO closes it, OR you need to destroy the object assign a `null`.

Because finally the code suggested by @Alex, with these small changes, was working, I was able to get the errors from PHP highlighting the above details.
Please here below the final working code, hoping that can be useful to any other had my same issue:

```
/**
 * MySQL - try to open it. If it fails, 
 * it returns which error and continues the execution of the script
 */
try {
    $sql = new PDO($pdo_servername, $username, $password, $pdo_options);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'MySQL connection failed: ' . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    $sql = false;
}

/**
 * SQLite - try to open it. If it fails, 
 * it returns which error and continues the execution of the script
 */
try {
    $sqlite = new PDO($pdo_servername_sqlite3);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'SQLite connection failed: '. "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    $sqlite = false;
}

/**
 * If the connection is made, it executes the Query
 * If anything wrong with the Query insertion, an error is returned.
 * The script continues
 */
if ($sql != false) {

  $ret = $sql->exec($query);

  if(!$ret){
      print_r($sql->errorInfo());  // THIS is the valid method for PDO Exec and returns an array
  } else {
      echo "New record created successfully on MySQL DB";   
  }
}

if ($sqlite != false) {

  $retlite = $sqlite->exec($query);

  if(!$retlite){
      print_r($sqlite->errorInfo());  // THIS is the valid method for PDO Exec and returns an array
  } else {
      echo "New record created successfully on SQLite3 DB"; 
  }

}

/**
 * Closes the DB Connections
 */
$sql = null;
$sqlite = null;
```

Thanks to all of you for your valid help. I very much appreciated it :)